# Rollup: bundle in order

Tags: javascript, rollup, rollupjs

I've been trying to get acquainted with Rollup for a few days, and one thing has left me confused. Rollup always groups the contents of an imported script at the beginning of the file, regardless of the correct position at the end of the file to which it is being imported. This is a problem for very long synchronous scripts.

Does Rollup not support this, or am I not sure how to configure it correctly?

I'm using it via CLI, with the settings file (rollup.config.js). It works well, except in the situation I mentioned above.

Can you help with that?

**Edit:**
First of all: it is a mere example.

Suppose I have two files, one called `index.js` and the other called `maths.js`, the latter being imported by the first.

// index.js

```
/**
 * License ...
 */

let numbers = {};
numbers.property = "This is a static variable";
numbers.base = 1000;

// Module maths
import {maths} from "./maths";
numbers.maths = maths;

// Testing
console.log(numbers.maths.sum(10, 20))
```

// maths.js

```
let maths = {};

maths.sum = function(x, y) {
    return example.base + x + y;
}

export {maths};
```

**Expected result: index.js outputed**

```
/**
 * License ...
 */

let numbers = {};
numbers.property = "This is a static variable";
numbers.base = 1000;

let maths = {};

maths.sum = function(x, y) {
    return example.base + x + y;
};
numbers.maths = maths;

console.log(numbers.maths.sum(10, 20));
```

**Real result: index.js outputed**

```
let maths = {};

maths.sum = function(x, y) {
    return example.base + x + y;
};

/**
 * License ...
 */


let numbers = {};
numbers.property = "This is a static variable";
numbers.base = 1000;
numbers.maths = maths;


console.log(numbers.maths.sum(10, 20));
```

Note that the Rollup does not follow the order of the code in the import. This is important for synchronous code.

Comment: Can you add some more detail and ideally a code sample of your input and what your desired output is?

Comment: @ed. I tried to explain it in the most summarized and precise way.

Comment: Can you explain *why* the order outputted by Rollup will not work for you - looks good to me? Also I'm not sure what you mean by 'synchronous code'.

Comment: I started a personal project (which I intend to publish in the future), with about 10k lines, last year. It is difficult to maintain, especially because I am half beginner.

The way I found it was to divide the code into modules, assigning several different variables to make the export feasible. But the code follows the exact execution sequence as it was written, from start to finish (a different methodology from this causes an error). That is, the way Rollup imports causes problems. [1]

Comment: And, after all, it is not aesthetically interesting, either, since even the license that should be at the top of the file, and ends up being entangled in the middle of the code.

All I need is for Rollup to import at the exact point where they were called. And this is what I'm lost at. [end]

Comment: Can you update the example above with code that will **break** when bundled with rollup? I suspect that you may be using modules in an unexpected way? Also note that a bundle isn't optimised for readability.

Answer (score 4):

Rollup is following the spec. When you use a native module loader in a browser, if `index.js` imports `maths.js`, then `math.js` will be loaded *and executed* before `index.js` is executed. (If `math.js` has dependencies of its own, they will also be loaded and executed first, etc etc etc.)

So if you want to have some code that runs before an import declaration, you will have to put that code in a different module and import it first:

```js
// numbers.js
export let numbers = {};
numbers.property = "This is a static variable";
numbers.base = 1000;
```

```js
// index.js
import {numbers} from './numbers';
import {maths} from './maths';
numbers.maths = maths;

console.log(numbers.maths.sum(10, 20))
```

Comment: I tried, and it didn't work out very well.
Is there no configuration that makes Rollup behave differently? Or another bundler?

Comment: This is how modules work. Don't fight it. If there is another bundler that has the incorrect behaviour you seek (I don't think there is), it will cause you regret in other ways. Just fix your program